# Why are all my snap directories empty even though I have apps installed there?

Tags: snap

If I browse to ~/snap all of the directories contained inside are empty. Also, if I ls -a in terminal I get,

```
intellij-idea-community/current $ sudo ls -la
total 8
```

But no files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snap folder under your home directory is not where snaps are installed. It's simply the confined path tree for where those apps are allowed to read/write user data from (barring any exceptions granted by the user).

The actual snaps are in a different system-wide location, and mounted on yet another location for use.

Answer (score 0):

Snap files are in `/var/lib/snapd/snap/`